# play with windows 7 on vmware

Tags: windows-7, virtualization

is there anyway to install windows 7 inside vmware 6.5 ?

note : my OS is windows xp sp 2

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The templates are just templates. They automatically tell VMWare the best settings for certain environments such as Disk Type (Scsi, IDE), and what version of tools to use etc.

VMWare can run practically any X86 or x64 based machine without problem.

That being said, if you choose Vista as the OS Template, you will maintain all the compatibility as it is pretty much the same OS

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this can easily be done.

Well it works in VirtualBox anyway so I can't see a reason why it shouldn't in Vmware.

You just need to mount the windows 7 ISO and it should install fine.